# What should be the structure of a blog?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

It is the first time I'm developing a blog, I want to see if I get this right.
Elements:

1. html page that will display the blog messages
2. javascript that will sent a get/post request onload to get all the blog posts from DB(MySQL)
3. PHP page that will get the get/post request to bring/edit/delete a page and will fetch/edit/delete       the appropriate item in DB.
4. MySQL DB that will store all post items in DB

Flow:

html <--onload()--> javascript <--edit(id)/get(all)/delete(id)--> php <--delete/update/insert-->MySQL

Is that the way to do it? is there a better or easier way I'm creating this blog to practice JavaScript/PHP/HTML.

Comment: Your javascript layer is unnecessary, the php script can output data to the html page directly. Javascript should be used to allow the user to dynamically interact with the page, rather than load data from the php script.

Comment: Yes but as the blog administrator I would like to add/edit/delete posts and  I want to do it dynamically without touching the DB directly. Anyway I couldn't find any way that PHP can change elements by ID in a html.

Comment: **Use WordPress!** I always say **roll your own** but to you I say: *use WordPress*...

Comment: First what is WorPress? Why would you recommend that, I spend three weeks learning Javascript/PHP/HTML 14 hours per day and now you tell me to use something else? Anyway I already almost completed the blog using those methods I just want to know if that is the way to do that

Comment: @AlonMelanker WordPress is a blogging engine. It will give you an idea of a blog's features. But it works great as a blog. No need to reinvent it. If you need a blog use WP, if you need something else... write it. But you can also learn to build themes and plugins for WP. It's a universe of its own... might be worth a look. From your question, I'm afraid you don't have the understanding to tackle such a project right now. Start small...

Comment: @AlonMelanker I've spent 10 years learning PHP and I'm still learning :) ... more or less. Less!

Comment: Use [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) without any argument.

Comment: @CodeAngry: I almost completed my Blog and it is working that way, I'm just not sure that is the way to do it and if there are better ways without taking shortcuts. I'm building this blog to practice PHP/HTML/JavaScript

Comment: @AlonMelanker Then... just use WP to learn how it works and its features :)

Comment: @AlonMelanker, If for learning/practice then it's ok but for serious blogging there is no alternative of WordPress, none can say that and not only for bloging, WordPress is being used as a `CMS` too and I think half of the Websites built with WordPress.

Comment: @CodeAngry: I'd certainly look in the future at WP. But right now I want to study JavaScript,PHP and HTML due to a market demand in my country. I really want to know if that is the way to do it using those  languages

Comment: @AlonMelanker WP is doing it in `THOSE LANGUAGES`. Why do you think I recommended it? Go to wordpress.org now and download it.

Comment: @CodeAngry Okay I'd give it a try

Comment: Don't listen to that WordPress bullshit, your ideas seem fine. Learning by doing is always a better idea than just looking at a complete system (which also isn't nicely coded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's one way to do it and it's fine.
Yes, it's good for learning purposes, but if you want to actually run a blog, better use WordPress;
If you plan to become a blog-builder, better practice on build WordPress themes;
I'm not sure about your relationship with the DBAdmin, but you're going to interact with the DB in using PHP whether you use javascript or not.
PHP cannot change an HTML element dynamically, but you can reconstruct the page on the server-side and provide the client with a new page for every action (at some rare scenarios it might actually be faster any it doesn't rely on the client-side capabilities- not everyone have javascript, you know...)